# не срабатывает blur с первого раза

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

в данном случае событие при потере фокуса не срабатывает с первого раза. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#time_of_purchase").blur(function(){
      var time_parts = $("#time_of_purchase").val().split(':');
      if ((time_parts['0']>24)||(time_parts['1']>59)){
        $('#btn_submit').attr('disabled', 'true');
      }
      else {
        $('#btn_submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: У меня всё срабатывает с первого раза. Может, вы не поняли проблему и на самом деле проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь сравнить строку с числом?

Comment: По приведению типов проблем со сравнением строки и числа быть не должно, они оба будут сравниваться как числа. Скорее всего вопрос сформулирован неверно и единственное что могу предположить: Скажем если написать в поле "24:60", то потом можно нажать кнопку и только после этого она станет неактивной, но запрос при этом все равно отработает (раз уж кнопка "submit"). Верно ли мое предположение и в этом ли вы видите проблему? Если же нет, то вроде в остальном никаких проблем не наблюдаю которые бы могли повлиять на срабатывание с первого раза.